# Cocoa CALayer not displaying NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, calayer, nsimage

Having issues displaying a NSImage in a CALayer

```
 init(image: NSImage) {
     self.image = image
     super.init(frame: .zero)
 }

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

 override func viewWillDraw() {
     super.viewWillDraw()
     animationLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
     animationLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
     animationLayer.contents = image.cgImage
     animationLayer.masksToBounds = true
     animationLayer.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor

     wantsLayer = true
     layer?.addSublayer(animationLayer)
 }
```

The CALayer with the `backgroundColor` set as blue is rendering fine, but the `NSImage` is not. The `NSImage` is confirmed as containing the required image and is set on initialisation of the class.

Having developed the same within the iOS Framework, I am struggling to see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike in iOS the `image` property of `CALayer` in macOS considers `NSImage` rather than its `CGImage` representation.

```
animationLayer.contents = image
```

Comment: Removed my last comment as it's actually worked ;) Thanks